# Atom source full of syntax errors

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, atom-editor

Recently wanted to look in to atom editor, but, when looking at the source, i see that there are plenty of errors in .js files like syntax errors.

Could someone shine some light on me, why popular project has so many syntax errors (or am i missing something?)?

By syntax errors, this is what i mean (missing semicolons & even code, that is not javascript valid code.):

[image]
[image]

Comment: Don't put in your question a picture of some code, put the code (which looks valid from there) directly in the question. BTW it's possible you're confused because your tools don't understand ES6

Comment: It's ES2015 code. Missing semicolons aren't errors (to some people :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see there is indeed valid syntax.

**Semicolons** can (mostly) be omitted in JavaScript and are optional. It is a question of convention whether you use them or not.

The syntax you can see in the screenshot is [**valid ES2015 syntax**](https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/).

Answer (score 2):

Semicolons are not strictly required for most JavaScript to run.

The code you posted contains ES2015 syntax, which is perfectly valid JavaScript.